# Update different rows's column with different value from another table

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I am having a postgres table called poi as below:

```
TABLE1 : 

gz_id| rt_id | gz_name | rt_name | gz_acc | rt_acc
23              sabah                414

TABLE2 : 

rt_id | rt_name | rt_acc
44     sabah_101   414
```

How can i update table 1 to achieve the result as below?

```
TABLE1 : 

gz_id| rt_id | gz_name | rt_name | gz_acc | rt_acc
23       44     sabah    sabah_101  414      414
```

I tried using update as below but it doesn't work. It updates all other rows with same values.

Tried with query below, didn't work:

Query:

```
Update table 1
set t1.rt_id = t2.rt_id,
set t1.rt_name = t2.rt_name,
set t1.rt_acc = t2.rt_acc
from t2 
where t1.rt_acc = t2.rt_acc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
UPDATE table1 
   SET rt_id = table2.rt_id,
       rt_name = table2.rt_name, 
       rt_acc = table2.rt_acc       
  FROM table2 
  WHERE gz_acc = table2.rt_acc;
```

Comment: Hi there..i need to do a update into table 1 columns from table 2

Comment: to make an update you need to know which row you are updating i.e. on what basis do you map from row of table1 to row on table2?

Comment: Example of SQL Query:

    Update table 1
    set t1.rt_id = t2.rt_id,
    set t1.rt_name = t2.rt_name,
    set t1.rt_acc = t2.rt_acc
    from t2 
    where t1.rt_acc = t2.rt_acc

however, this doesn't work

Comment: @Derek you were very close. You missed the table name for t2. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks..apparently i can't get it work its because my mistake on matching the column from table 1 to table 2. Thanks alot for your advice..cheers!